# Issues while building apk using android platforn in ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Good morning. I'm newer in ionic and face this issues since 3 day.
node -v: v5.8.0
npm -v: 3.7.3
cordova -v: 6.4.0
ionic -v: 2.2.1
java -version:  openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"
                     OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
                     OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

**when I try : >ionic build android**

I have this issues

:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
~/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /home/donvex/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.544 secs

Error: /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/pneupur_app//platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
~/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: ~/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Some body help me :worried:

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 32bit dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install -y lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
```